# Whats the best way to iterate over circular wrapped indices?

Tags: rust, iteration

To loop over indices, keeping track of the next/previous items, it can be done as follows.

```
for index_prev in 0..n {
    let index_next = (index_prev + 1) % n;

    // some arbitrary code...
    some_function(index_prev, index_next);
}
```

This can be made more efficient by avoiding the modulo, and instead doing:

*Providing the index wrapping can be offset by one .*

```
let mut index_prev = n - 1;
for index_next in 0..n {

    // some arbitrary code...
    some_function(index_prev, index_next);

    index_prev = index_next;
}
```

While this works, it has some downsides:

- `index_prev` needs to be declared mutable, when we really want to loop over immutable indices.
- `index_prev` needs to be declared in the outer scopes name-space, instead of being limited to the for loop.

While neither of these are *terrible* they make the solution less than ideal.

---

Is there a performant & convenient way to do this in Rust or does it require writing a custom iterator?

Whats the best way to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 4):

```
fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    for (prev, next) in (0..n).zip(1..n+1) {
        println!("{}, {}", prev, next % n);
    }
}
```

Gives you:

```
0, 1
1, 2
....
9, 0
```

Or if you REALLY don't want to use the modulo, then:

```
for (prev, next) in (0..n).zip((0..n).cycle().skip(1)) {
```

will work, but likely generate even more code.

Another alternative is to wrap the required type in your own implementation of iteration or `[x]` getter, which handles the overflow correctly. That is, always gets `[x%n]` from the underlying structure.

Comment: the down side of the first example is you need to use `next % n` whenever you reference it. Accidentally using `vector[next]` for example will cause an index error (besides the possible overhead of using modulo each time, and extra typing required).

Comment: @ideasman42 You know that unless this is the centre of some CPU-heavy hot loop, an extra module is not going to be noticeable, right? Another alternative is just to wrap your buffer into a structure implementing higher indices and doing the wrap around transparently - it doesn't get rid of it, but makes it impossible to forget about it.

Comment: Right, my main concern is that `vector[next]` reads as correct code but wouldn't work, or worse - silently reads past the intended bounds. Also in practice `n` may be `path.to.some.vector.len()`, making `vector[next % path.to.some.vector.len()]` tedious to write out.

Comment: @ideasman42 Implement it into your type then. You can define your own `[x]` where `x = x % self.len()`.

Comment: @viraptor that's a great solution that probably gets to the root of the problem. Instead of pushing the wrapping logic to the consumer, encode that logic within a new type. +1. I'd encourage you to add it to your answer.